# RecyclerView endless scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried to  implement recylerview endless listview in android .Everything is working fine. Called my asynctask again in handler for scroll listener which is an another thread and sleep for some time ,but i don't want to call any calls in handler ,if in that case i am not able to see my progress bar at the bottom which loads very fast and not visible.How could i achieve this,kindly suggest me.

this is my Main activity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    Activity _activity;
    private String jsonResult;
    boolean loadingMore = false;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    private TextView tvEmptyView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DataAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private List<Student> dataArrayList;
    private LoadJsonData loadJsonData;
    protected Handler handler;
    private int count;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        _activity = this;
        loadJsonData = new LoadJsonData();
        tvEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        dataArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        handler = new Handler();
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Android Endless Scrollling data ");

        }

//        loadData();
        if (dataArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            loadJsonData.execute();
        }

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(dataArrayList, mRecyclerView);

        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        if (dataArrayList.isEmpty() && count > 0) {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
//                //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                dataArrayList.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dataArrayList.size());
//
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//                        //   remove progress item
//                        studentList.remove(studentList.size() - 1);
//                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(studentList.size());
//                        //add items one by one
//                        int start = studentList.size();
//                        int end = start + 20;
                        new LoadJsonData().execute();
//                        for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
//                            studentList.add(new Student("Student " + i, "AndroidStudent" + i + "@gmail.com"));
//                            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size());
//                        }
//                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                        //or you can add all at once but do not forget to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 1000);


            }
        });

    }

    private class LoadJsonData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        //        ProgressDialog progress;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (dataArrayList.size() == 0) {

                progress = ProgressDialog.show(_activity, "Progress",
                        "Please wait", true);
            } else {
                dataArrayList.remove(dataArrayList.size() - 1);
//                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataArrayList.size()-);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String jsonResult = "";
            loadingMore = true;
//            lv.removeFooterView(footerView);
//            jsonResult=get("https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php");
//            return jsonResult;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = "";
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(request);
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    jsonResult = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                } else {
                    jsonResult = "Did not work!";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "GET failed", e);
            }

            return jsonResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progress.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject dataJsontObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray dataJsonArray = dataJsontObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray dataSubArray = dataJsonArray.getJSONArray(i);

                    Student dataObject = new Student();
                    dataObject.setName((String) dataSubArray.get(0));
                    dataObject.setType((String) dataSubArray.get(1));
                    dataObject.setProfession((String) dataSubArray.get(2));
                    dataObject.setCountry((String) dataSubArray.get(3));
                    dataObject.setCurrency((String) dataSubArray.get(5));

//                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void run() {
//                        //   remove progress item
//                        studentList.remove(studentList.size() - 1);
//                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(studentList.size());
//                        //add items one by one
//                        int start = studentList.size();
//                        int end = start + 20;
//
//                        for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
//                            studentList.add(new Student("Student " + i, "AndroidStudent" + i + "@gmail.com"));
//                            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size());
//                        }
//                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
//                       //or you can add all at once but do not forget to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                    }
//                }, 2000);
//                    lv.addFooterView(footerView);
                    dataArrayList.add(dataObject);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dataArrayList.size());

                }
                count++;
                mAdapter.setLoaded();
//                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                loadingMore = false;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


    // load initial data
//    private void loadData() {
//
////        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
////            studentList.add(new Student("Student " + i, "androidstudent" + i + "@gmail.com"));
////
////        }
//        loadJsonData.execute();
//
//
//    }

    public static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }

}
```

DataAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    private List<Student> studentList;


    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;


    public DataAdapter(List<Student> students, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        studentList = students;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();


            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return studentList.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            vh = new StudentViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progress_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof StudentViewHolder) {

            Student singleStudent = (Student) studentList.get(position);

            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).name.setText(singleStudent.getName());
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).type.setText(singleStudent.getType());
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).profession.setText(singleStudent.getProfession());
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).country.setText(singleStudent.getCountry());
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).currency.setText(singleStudent.getCurrency());

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }


    //
    public static class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView type;
        public TextView profession;
        public TextView country;
        public TextView currency;

        public StudentViewHolder(View convertView) {
            super(convertView);
            name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            profession = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profession);
            country = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            currency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.currecy);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this code :

full source code : [github.com](https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/EndlessRecyclerview)

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<String> {

private  int count=0;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
@InjectView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mStaggeredLayoutManager;
private final RecyclerBinderAdapter<TitleSection, CardViewType> adapter
        = new RecyclerBinderAdapter<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


    // Lookup the swipe container view
    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
    // Setup refresh listener which triggers new data loading
    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Your code to refresh the list here.
            // Make sure you call swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false)
            // once the network request has completed successfully.
            fetchTimelineAsync(count);
            count++;
        }
    });

    mStaggeredLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mStaggeredLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Configure the refreshing colors
    swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    fetchTimelineAsync(0);
    count++;

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://xomorod.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    SimpleService.StackOverflowAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(SimpleService.StackOverflowAPI.class);

    Call<String> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions("android");
    //asynchronous call
    call.enqueue(this);
}


public void fetchTimelineAsync(int page) {




}

@Override
public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);


        CardPic cardPic=new CardPic(this,new PicData("Title" +response.body(),response.body(),"https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/04/10/00/41/yellow-715540_960_720.jpg"));
        adapter.add(TitleSection.SECTION_3, cardPic);


}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    String ss=t.getMessage();
    ss=ss+"sss";
}
```

Comment: Thank you replying ,i tried your source code to migrate in android studio ,but it's not working .